# R - Remove elements in a vector that appear more than once

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following vector

```
vec <- rep(1:20,sample(1:5, 20, replace = T))
table(vec)
```

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
 1  5  4  3  5  2  1  1  3  5  3  2  3  1  5  5  3  1  4  1
```

I want to only keep the numbers that appear once. Anything that appears more than once, I want to remove it. So in the end I'd like to end up with

```
1  7  8 14 18 20
```

At the moment, I'm generating this with the following command

```
vec2 <- names(which(table(vec) == 1))
vec2
```

But I'm wondering if there's a beeter (and more efficient) way of doing this.

Comment: Try `vec[!vec %in% vec2]`

Comment: `data.table::data.table(vec)[, .N, vec][N == 1, vec]` is much faster than table for larger vectors

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%` and negate (`!`) create a logical vector based on the OP's code

```
vec[!vec %in% vec2]
```

Or in a single line using `ave` and `length`

```
vec[ave(seq_along(vec), vec, FUN = length)>1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, I'm trying to do it another way, that doesn't require what I had to do to get `vec2`. The second piece of code you provided, doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @ZuhaibAhmed Is it the same example you tried or different?  Because this is working for me.  Do you have a factor column?  I would change it to `vec[ave(seq_along(vec), vec, FUN = length)>1]`

Comment: Oh sorry, it does work. I didn't realize that you had `>1` instead of `==` in your code snippet. Thank you!